# How to check if file got downloaded from browser using selenium2library

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

Can someone help me How to check if file got downloaded from browser using selenium2library,RobotFramework.In my current test I am able to click the download button and file is getting downloaded but what happens if the file didn't get downloaded eventhough button is clicked. Any sample code is helpful.

Comment: Selenium2Library handles only things that happen inside browser. You should use OperatingSystem library to check that file exists on disk. Maybe use "File Should Exist" keyword

Comment: Thank you @Pekka , Any possibility to give auto-download option in browser to particular directory

Comment: Can i know File Should Exist keyword is platform independent or not ? My tests need to execute on Linux and windows platforms

Comment: code that i am trying is as follows,please let me know what is wrong in that                                                         ${preferences} =    Create Dictionary   browser.download.folderList = 2  browser.download.dir = C:/Users/mra001/Downloads/Cambium_Builds
    open browser    ${cnMaestro_URL}    ${Browser}    desired_capabilities=${preferences}

Comment: Unfortunately Selenium2Library Open Browser keyword documentation says you can use desired_capabilities only if you are using a remote server. This would explain why your code does not work. I think a workaround is to create a new firefox profile and load it with ff_profile_dir parameter. Check Firefox profiles from here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Answer (score 5):

In chrome I open the `chrome://downloads` page and then retrieve the downloaded files list from shadow DOM like this:

```
const docs = document
  .querySelector('downloads-manager')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloads-list')
  .getElementsByTagName('downloads-item');
```

This solution is restrained to chrome, the data also contains information like file path and download date.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link - 
http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html

Also, here's how you can auto-download the file to a particular directory -

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", @"c:\path\to\downloads \folder");   
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Your answer shouldn't have a link to your blog. There are exceptions if you link to a specific blog entry that is relevant. If you want to advertise your blog, please put it on your profile page.

Comment: @BryanOakley  can you please help me in correcting my code  ${preferences} =    Create Dictionary   browser.download.folderList = 2  browser.download.dir = C:/Users/mra001/Downloads/Cambium_Builds
    open browser    ${cnMaestro_URL}    ${Browser}    desired_capabilities=${preferences}

Answer (score 0):

u can use following python function to download file without showing dialog box.

Also u can set preference for which type of files save file dialog box should not get displayed.

```
def create_profile():
    from selenium import webdriver
    fp =webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",'C:/Users/mra001/Downloads/Cambium_Builds')
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",'text/csv/xls')
    fp.update_preferences()
    return fp.path
```

Comment: what is the valid path to give .I have tried c:\\Users\\mra001 and c:/Users/mra001..In all cases I am getting error as below      ` WebDriverException: Message: Target URL create_profile is not well-formed.
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.get (file:///c:/users/mra001/appdata/local/temp/tmpgb0b3o/webdriver-py-profilecopy/extensions/
fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10636)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/mra001/appdata/local/temp/tmpgb0b3o/webdriver-py-profile `

Comment: I am giving as C:\\temp. It works without any issue. Make sure that path exists.